# Insert HTML code into the Editor in SharePoint on click of Custom Ribbon action

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I am inserting a piece of code to the Page, when a ribbon named "Insert Code" which is present in the ribbon is clicked. Here is the code i use:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
            function Warn()
{
            var href = '<div class="my-class"><h1>The Header</h1><p>The paragraph of text</p>';

       var range = RTE.Cursor.get_range();
                 range.deleteContent();
                 var selection = range.parentElement();
                 if (!selection) {
                     return;
                 }
                 var span = selection.ownerDocument.createElement('span');
                 span.innerText = href;
                 range.insertNode(span);
                 RTE.Cursor.get_range().moveToNode(span);
                 //Range.pasteHtml(href);
                 RTE.Cursor.update();                   
    }     
            //]]>

         </script>
```

I am able to add the code on the page. But its inserted as below, rather than the actual html tags. Any info on how can i get it corrected?

```
&lt;div class=&quot;my-class&quot;&gt;         &lt;h1&gt;The Header&lt;/h1&gt;         &lt;p&gt;The paragraph of text&lt;/p&gt;         &lt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting span.innerHTML instead:

```
span.innerHTML = href;
```

Comment: Got a query in between, once the "piece of code" as per the question above got inserted to the text editor, the cursor is getting disappeared. any way to get is available after the code which i have placed?